# Saving data into a text file sent as JSON with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have currently a problem with my code. I would like to send JSON data with Ajax to a PHP script but it doesn't work. What does work is that the PHP script can be called by the Ajax code but it can't put the code into the .txt file. I have tried several things but I can't get it working. (I am trying to set the users array in the .txt file)

jQuery code:

```
          var users = [];              

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: hostURL + "sendto.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: { json: JSON.stringify(users) },
              success: function (data) {
                  alert(data);
              }
          });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['json'];
$data = json_decode($json);

$file = fopen('test.txt','w+');
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);

echo 'Success?';
?>
```

Comment: `$data` is an object in your code which is why you can't write it to the file, just write `$json` to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know that in PHP `json_decode` generates an Array that you can't write into an text file.

So only remove the `json_decode` command.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. Learned again something new today :)

Comment: No Problem I started with 13 years and I am now 14 and without mistackes you cant learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Since `json_decode()` function returns an array, you can use `file_put_contents()` that will save each array element on its own line

```
<?php
  $json = $_POST['json'];
  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  file_put_contents('test.txt',implode("\n", $data));
?>
```